# sorting NSmutable array contains object according to double value

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa, nsmutablearray, sql-order-by

I want to order `NSMutableArray` contain objects according to two of object property one of them has `double` type second has `NSString` ?

I tried to use this method but I got exception :

```
NSString * LASTNAME = @"lastName";
NSString * GRADE = @"grade";

NSSortDescriptor *lastDescriptor =
    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
        initWithKey:LASTNAME
          ascending:YES
           selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSSortDescriptor *firstDescriptor =
    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
        initWithKey:GRADE
          ascending:YES
           selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

NSArray * descriptors =
   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:lastDescriptor, firstDescriptor, nil];
NSArray * sortedArray =
   [students sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

@interface Student : NSObject
{
    NSString * firstName;
    NSString * lastName;
    double grade;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Numbers don't have a case, try using compare: for GRADE

After Edit:  You didn't say what error you got.  Did the code you posted even compile?  You have a typo in your firstDescriptor -- one too many "]" at the end of the method.  You probably fixed that when you took out the compare: (which shouldn't have fixed anything).

Answer (score 1):

NSNumber doesn't respond to `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`. You want just plain `compare:` for the number.

Comment: should i make grade NSNumber instead of double I tried compare but I got exception again?

Comment: @salamonti: Key-Value Coding will return an NSNumber for a double, so that wouldn't be a problem. What is the exact exception you're getting?

Comment: you are right and I solved it by remove compare also so it will be
NSSortDescriptor *firstDescriptor =
    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
        initWithKey:GRADE
          ascending:YES]];

Comment: Really?  That worked?  I thought that compare: was the default, so removing compare: shouldn't do anything, should it?

Comment: @rdelmar i didn't see the result yet if it was working write I will add it as right answer

Comment: @rdelmar: It is the default. I'm guessing salamonti left off the colon, which is of course not a real comparison method selector.

Answer (score 0):

Remove localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare

```
NSSortDescriptor *firstDescriptor =
    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
        initWithKey:GRADE
          ascending:YES]];
```

Comment: This code will not compile -- once again, you have an extra "]" at the end.